# Altering virtual functions to add new parameters

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have a base class `A` (which is never instantiated in its base form) that is the parent to many many child classes. `A` has a function that every child class inherits, called `func`. Each child class has a different implementation of `func` but the input and output of each is the same.

in A

```
virtual void func();
```

and in each child class

```
void func();
```

While maintaining this code I realized i actually want to pass a parameter to this function, like so

```
virtual void func(float foo);
```

I then, apparently naively, assumed each class inheriting this function would then be able to take and use this parameter but it seems I am now going to have to go through each and every child class and add `float foo` to their implementation of the definition of `func()`, adding `void func(float foo);` for each of them. Isn't this kind of duplicated alters exactly what OOP is supposed to help avoid? I can access base class members without the need to duplicate their declarations. My question is am I misusing `virtual` functions, is there a way to get the behavior I want or is this just something that is a pain to change?

Comment: If you change interface, it seems natural that you have to change any class implementing this interface.

Comment: Another aspect of OOP is overloading, not just overriding.  func(TypeA &A) is different than func(TypeB &B), and they are both different than func().

Comment: Inheritance should prevent *definitions* from being duplicated. The *declaration* of an override indicates that a child class has custom behavior (in its override *definition*). What you find hard to implement actually allows your child class to create overloads with the same name, but different signature from the parent class. If you want to ensure that, use `override` and `final` keywords. Then, if the signature gets changed, child classes get alerted that they're no longer overriding the parent method but defining something new.

Comment: Unclear if you change `void func()` into `void func(float)`, or add another overload `void func(float)`. Issue with several overloads is that non overridden overloads would be hidden unless appropriate `using` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with to this problem is to create a data structure that I pass by reference into each of the inherited functions.

```
// in parent
virtual void func(Data * _data);
```

---

```
// in child
void func(Data * _data);
```

---

```
public struct Data
{
    float foo;
}
```

That way if i ever want to add aditional input to the functions I can simply alter

```
public struct Data
{
    float foo;

    int bar; // only changed here!
}
```

And not need to duplicate my edits all over the program (at perhaps a minor impact on performance, one additional memory lookup)